# Jest spy on functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am swapping to Jest from Mocha, and I'm wondering if there is a way to spy on a React method. For example, let's say I have the following method in my component (ignore the `sdk` library, it just constructs a jQuery Ajax call):

```
getData() {
    sdk.getJSON('/someURL').done(data => {
        this.setState({data});
    });
}
```

Using Sinon I would test this by spying on the prototype like so:

```
it('should call getData', () => {
    sinon.spy(Component.prototype, 'getData');
    mount(<Component />);
    expect(Component.prototype.getData.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
```

This would ensure code coverage without mocking the method. Is there similar functionality in Jest?

EDIT: Also, if this functionality doesn't exist, what is the next best strategy for testing API calls?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is the [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) method, that was introduced with v19 some days ago, that does exactly what you are looking for

Comment: would've been a better answer if you've provided sample usage here, along with your own explanation instead of just posting a link in the answer.

Comment: This answer is even harmful, as it suggests to use the global spyOn which (in my understanding) comes with jasmine-jest2 package to ease migration from jasmine. However, the behaviour seems to be different from jest.spyOn() in that global spyOn (like jasmine's one) doesn't call through by default!

Answer (score 73):

Actually you can use jest.spyOn [jest.spyOn](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname)

If method is called when component created use:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'; 

describe('My component', () => {
  it('should call getData', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'getData');
    mount(<Component />);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  });
})
```

or if you have it in your DOM and method use **bind** you can use:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'; 

describe('My component', () => {
  it('should call getData', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'getData');
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  });
})
```

Answer (score 17):

You could go for the new `spyOn` method or the following should also work fine.

```
it('should call getData', () => {
    Component.prototype.getData = jest.fn(Component.prototype.getData);
    expect(Component.prototype.getData).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: is ```Sinon.spy``` same as ```jest.spyOn```?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Jest with React 16.8 - This worked for me:

```js
  it("lifecycle method should have been called", () => {
    jest.spyOn(RedirectingOverlay.prototype, 'componentWillUnmount');
    jest.spyOn(RedirectingOverlay.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    const wrapper = mount(<RedirectingOverlay message="Hi There!"/>);
    expect(RedirectingOverlay.prototype.componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    wrapper.unmount()
    expect(RedirectingOverlay.prototype.componentWillUnmount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Also using:

- `"enzyme": "^3.6.0"`
- `"jest": "23.5.0"`
- `"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0"`