# Testing a service method in component method, jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

Im new to jest, however wrote a unit test how one would write the test in jasmine...

```
      it('should run onOpenChannelModal correctly', fakeAsync(() => {
    const extractChannelDataSpy = jest.spyOn(channelService, 'extractChannelData');

    expect(component.showFullChannelList).toEqual(false);
    component.onOpenChannelModal(selectedChannelData);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(extractChannelDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <= fails here
    expect(component.showFullChannelList).toEqual(true);
  }));
```

However fails on expect(extractChannelDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

Could someone inform me where I am going wrong?

Here is the component method:

```
  onOpenChannelModal($event: any) {
    this.selectedChannel = $event;
    this.selectedChannelMedia = this.channelService.extractChannelData(this.selectedChannel);
    this.showFullChannelList = true;
  }
```

Comment: The following article answered my question, thanks... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430368/jest-spy-on-functionality

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
  it('should run onOpenChannelModal correctly', () => {
    spyOn(channelService, 'extractChannelData');

    expect(component.showFullChannelList).toEqual(false);
    component.onOpenChannelModal(selectedChannelData);
  
    expect(channelService.extractChannelData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.showFullChannelList).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Comment: I think there also could be 
jest.spyOn(service, "methodName")
If you are not using Jasmine, but pure JEST